# Teechart Legend Style

Tags: activex, teechart

In My Code there is requirement when user click on a Bar of a series the CheckBox Style of the Series should be changed to none.But when i do that my Chart Width is increasing. IS there any way we can keep the chart width fix irrespective of legend table width.

Thanks
Akshay

Answer (score 1):

Set your legend Alignment in bottom for Avoiding width increment of chart as below.
Chart.GetLegend().SetAlignment(laBottom);

if you want custom position of legend (Right side of chart)then you can do as below. 
  m_Chart1.GetLegend().SetCustomPosition(TRUE);

m_Chart1.GetLegend().SetPositionUnits(muPercent);

m_Chart1.GetLegend().SetTopPercent(20);
  long leftmargin = 80.0;
  m_Chart1.GetLegend().SetLeftPercent(leftmargin );

m_Chart1.GetPanel().SetMarginRight(100-leftmargin+1);//for avoiding overlapping of legend and chart
Also you can finetune your legend and chart by modifying above value

Answer (score 1):

This Can be done

```
    GetLegend().SetResizeChart(false);
    GetLegend().SetCustomPosition(true);
    GetLegend().SetPositionUnits(muPercent);
    GetLegend().SetLeftPercent(83);
    GetLegend().SetTopPercent(10);
```